# Display a summation of a data table column on the footer of the column

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

For example,

```
<p:dataTable var="price" value="#{testManagedBean.price}" rowIndexVar="rowIndex">

    <p:column headerText="Index">
        <h:outputText value="#{rowIndex+1}"/>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Price" style="text-align: right;">
        <h:outputText value="#{price}"/>

        <f:facet name="footer">
            <c:set var="total" value="${total+price}"/>
            <h:outputText value="#{total}"/>
        </f:facet>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

The managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public final class TestManagedBean implements Serializable
{
    private List<BigDecimal>price;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        price=new ArrayList<>();
        price.add(new BigDecimal(50));
        price.add(new BigDecimal(100));
        price.add(new BigDecimal(150));
        price.add(new BigDecimal(200));
        price.add(new BigDecimal(250));
        price.add(new BigDecimal(300));
    }

    public List<BigDecimal> getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
}
```

The total of list of items is to be displayed on the footer.

Is this possible to do this summation using JSTL or otherwise without having a method that does this summation in the backing bean itself?

Currently the operation with JSTL `<c:set>` yields `0` on the footer of the associated column.

Comment: Why don't you want to have the getTotal() method in the bean? I think it would be much better and you could use a standard converter to get the format correct

Comment: There a situation in my application in which I have to repeat a backing bean method in at least three beans. Instead if this summation could be done on the XHTML page then, I wouldn't have to repeat the same logic more than once (the associated converter is doing its job well on XHTML pages too which I didn't mention in this example for the sake of simplicity).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this works for me:

```
        <c:set var="total" value="0"/>
        <c:forEach items="#{testManagedBean.price}" var="t">
            <c:set var="total" value="#{total + t}"/>
        </c:forEach>
        <h:outputText value="#{total}"/>
```

I will not reject the idea it might be optimizable :-)